# How to modify the requests generated by jmeter access log sampler?

Tags: jmeter

We want to simulate some load conditions captured in access log.
However, there is a parameter in query string, which changes
every day. So I need to modify the log file every time
I run the tests.

I was wondering is there any way to modify the request before it is sent to server?

Thanks,

Manish

Answer (score 0):

Using CSV Dataset Config from Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and this way is pretty standard: parametrize the request with variable/property.

Though if you need more specific answer - please be more specific in your description: show your suite and/or describe how exactly you let your requests into the JMeter.